# Pagination for dynamically generated content

Tags: vue.js, pagination

Consider the following code.

```js
<template>
  <div class="card-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
              <a @click="addCard()">Add Card</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
          <div class="row">
            <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index">
                <div class="card-panel">
                  <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>                  
                  <div class="card-action">
                    <a @click="deleteCard(index)">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  data: function() {
    return {
      cards: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addCard: function() {
      this.cards.push({
        description: "",
      });
    },    
    deleteCard: function(index) {
      this.cards.splice(index,1);
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

How to make the cards be grouped so that there are 4 rows and each row contains 4 cards? Upon reaching the fourth row the new cards go to the next page.

I thought I could use something like this [codepen.io/parths267/pen/bXbWVv](https://codepen.io/parths267/pen/bXbWVv)

But I have no idea how to get these cards organized in a pagination system.

The view would look something like this

[image: see prototype]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is calculate all cards of current page ahead.

Uses **computed property** to calculate the relate values which the pagination needs.

In below simple example (*it is only one example, you need to add necessary validations as your actual needs, like boundary conditions*) :

**pages** is the page count

**cardsOfCurPage** is the cards in current page

Then add one data property=**pageIndex** save the index of current page.

Anyway, keep data-driven in your mind.

1. List all arguments your pagination needs,
2. then declare them in data property or computed property.
3. execute the necessary calculations in computed property or methods.

*PS: I don't know which css framework you uses, so I uses bootstrap instead.*

```js
Vue.component('v-cards', {
  template: `<div class="card-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
              <a class="btn btn-danger" @click="addCard()">Add Card</a><span>Total Pages: {{pages}} Total Cards: {{cards.length}} Page Size:<input v-model="pageSize" placeholder="Page Size"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div v-for="(card, index) in cardsOfCurrPage" :key="index" class="col-3">
                <div class="card-panel">
                  <span class="card-title">Card Title: {{card.description}}</span>                  
                  <div class="card-action">
                    <a @click="deleteCard(index)">Delete</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <p><a class="badge" @click="gotoPrev()">Prev</a>- {{pageIndex + 1}} -<a class="badge" @click="gotoNext()">Next</a></p>
  </div>`,
  data: function() {
    return {
      cards: [],
      pageSize: 6,
      pageIndex: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pages: function () {
      return Math.floor(this.cards.length / this.pageSize) + 1
    },
    cardsOfCurrPage: function () {
      return this.cards.slice(this.pageSize * this.pageIndex, this.pageSize * (this.pageIndex+1))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addCard: function() {
      this.cards.push({
        description: this.cards.length,
      });
    },    
    deleteCard: function(index) {
      this.cards.splice(index,1);
    },
    gotoPrev: function() {this.pageIndex -=1},
    gotoNext: function() {this.pageIndex +=1}
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-cards></v-cards>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very good.
In the case of the computed pages function, did you use this way because it calculates in real time the number of cards?
"keep data-driven in your mind" I had item 1 in mind but i didn't know how to put it into pratice. I had thought of dividing the number of items per page using the id as reference.

Comment: Thank you. From here I think I can conclude what it would be like to display _m_ items in _n_ rows and the page numbers in the pagination.

Comment: in this case, the variable= **pages**  needs to be re-calculated **only when** count(cards) or page size is changed. so uses one computed property is the good practice. If go to next/prev page, it will not trigger the reactivity for computed property= **pages** (it will not be re-calc).

Comment: Thank you! Got it.